# Science fiction TV episode in which three young women meet a dying alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

Three young women meet a dying alien. They agree that they will add a year to their lives in order to give birth to the alien in the future. Only one of them however is chosen to give birth to the alien, which she does, and then gives the infant to her surgeon daughter, who is unable to bear children.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 15):

This is the 1995 Outer Limits series [season 2 episode 17 "Paradise"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/TheOuterLimits1995S2E17Paradise).

From the linked Tvtropes page:

> A dying alien woman who was the Last of Her Kind arrived on Earth in 1946 and met four young women. With their consent, she implanted an egg in each of their bodies so that her species would have a chance to survive. The eggs took 50 years to mature. The alien left a special light which, 50 years later, made the four women young again but only long enough to conceive. Three of them had sex with strangers in the attempt. Not only were they unable to conceive but they rapidly aged to death. Their bodies decomposed just as quickly. On the other hand, Helen is successful in conceiving a baby with Gerry, her late husband Charles' brother, as she had always been in love with him and vice versa. Within about an hour, Helen is heavily pregnant and about to give birth. **The resulting child appears to be a human girl, which Helen's daughter Dr. Christina Markham and her husband Grady intend to raise as their own since they can't have children.** Helen returns to her true age but her Alzheimer's has been cured as a gift from the alien.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. i have been searching the internet for the correct name for some time

Comment: @amikajulie Consider accepting the answer so other people can see it's been solved.